# Issue with binary subtraction

Tags: arithmetic, boolean-algebra

I was learning how to build a computer ALU, online, and the tutor comes up with a truth table which works perfectly and seems magical. 
One of the tasks was to find `x-y` (both x and y are 16-bit boolean buses)

'+' sign anywhere is the normal boolean addition operator and not the OR operator

On implementing boolean algebra on the truth table `x-y =  NOT(NOT(x)+y)`.
It works perfectly and I am not able to understand how it was derived.

I tried deriving the boolean logic myself and I came up with these steps:-

'+' anywhere is normal binary addition and not 'OR'

```
x-y = x+(-y)
-y = NOT(y) + 1    //2's complement
```

therefore,

```
x-y= x+(NOT(y) + 1)
```

and according to the truth table

```
x-y =  NOT(NOT(x)+y)
```

How is this working?? Can anyone please tell me how to think on these steps to derive such booleans functions?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you demonstrate it working on a small example? So far as I can see, it does **not** work if, say, $x=001011$ and $y=000110$: then $x-y=000101$, but $$x\land\neg y=001011\land 111001=001001\;.$$

Comment: ya sure(i am sorry that i couldn't upload the truth table because of my low rep score) chk out the truth table in this link (https://penguinyang.gitbooks.io/nand2tetris/chapter2-5.html)
 for example –
if its a 4 bit ALU and i want to compute 5-2
which in binary is 0101-0010 (lets say x=0101 and y= 0010)
heres how the truth table instructs me to proceed :-

x-y
step 1: NOT(x) : 1010 ; 
step 2: NOT(x)+y : 1010+0010 = 1100 ; 
step 3: NOT(NOT(x)+y) :NOT(1100)=0011 which is equal to 3

Comment: oh, I have actually made a mistake in my question. I have considered NOT(NOT(x)+y) as (x) AND ( NOT(y) ) using de morgan's law(It can't be used because '+'  is not OR but normal addition instead). BUT even if we consider  NOT(NOT(x)+y), how do we reach to this conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re doing $n$-bit arithmetic, $\neg x$ is $2^n-1-x$, the one’s complement of $x$. Thus,

$$\neg(\neg x+y)=2^n-1-(2^n-1-x+y)=x-y\;.$$

If you want to compare this with subtraction using the two’s complement, note that the two’s complement of an integer $x$ is $2^n-x$, so that

$$x+\neg y+1=x+2^n-1-y+1=x-y+2^n\;,$$

and you throw away the $2^n$ bit.

Using the example in my comment, for instance, with $n=6$, $x=11=001011_{\text{two}}$, and $y=6=000110_{\text{two}}$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\neg(\neg 001011+000110)&=\neg(110100+000110)\\
&=\neg111010\\
&=000101\;,
\end{align*}$$

while

$$001011+\neg 000110+1=001011+111001+1=(1)000101\;.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brian, means a lot. The 1s complement method was genious.

Comment: @Rohan: You're welcome; glad to help!